# image is not uploading in database

Tags: database, wordpress, image, upload

I am uploading image but it showed error in $DP_image.
I dont know why is happening.

```
 $DP_image=esc_sql($_FILES['getImage']['name']);
<label class="fofa">Upload Image</label>
<input type="button" name="btnImage"id="btnImage" class="form-control"
value="Upload Image">
<img src="" id="getImage" style="height:100px;width:100px;"/></div>

 <script>
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#btnImage").on("click",function(){
       var images = wp.media({
        title:"Upload Image",
        multiple:false
    }).open().on("select",function(e){
        var uploadedImages= images.state().get("selection").first();
        var selectedImages=uploadedImages.toJSON();
        jQuery("#getImage").attr("src",selectedImages.url);
    });  
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "*...but it showed error*" - what error? Please edit your question to include specific details of the error message. We are not mind readers, we can't help you fix an error when we don't know what it is! Please review [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [**Question Checklist**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/) to see what you need to give us so that we are able to help you.

Comment: It showed undefined index  getImage. due to it image is not uploaded in database.